# Play & Akka and blocking threads for database access

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, nonblocking

I want to make a call to a database which has lots of data and it might take a while to return.

I plan to do that work inside a call to Akka.future(f) and use an Async{} to render the response when the work is done.

Does it make sense to do that, or should I just do the long database call in the controller, without sending the work to Akka?

Or is there a way to do non blocking database access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response is blocked on completion of the database call, then it's only useful to make it asynchronous if you can get other work done towards assembling the response while the call runs.

Non blocking database access could mean a couple different things: A client library that gives you a callback based API, which would be pretty similar to the future solution, or one that uses non-blocking sockets to save on thread usage.  I'm assuming you mean the former, in which case I think it'd be functionally equivalent to using a future.

Comment: The DB call blocks and I have no other work to do for that incoming request.  But the Play server itself could handle another incoming request in the mean time.  But if I send the work to Akka.future(work), then its handled by the same threads which would handle any new incoming requests, so I don't think it makes any difference by passing it so Akka.  In fact it could even cause extra overhead.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think that makes sense.  Assuming blocking IO on the database call, it will occupy a thread until it's complete.  I don't know Play very well, but this shouldn't prevent any reasonable web framework from servicing additional requests.  Other threads can be scheduled on the CPU while waiting for packets from the DB server as with any other app, and Play should have a pool of threads available.  Accept answer if this makes sense. =)

Answer (score 4):

If you're forced to use a blocking driver for your database (if for some reason the async driver for MySQL doesn't work out) consider setting up an Actor pool (using routing) with a PinnedDispatcher.

The PinnedDispatcher provides a thread per actor and, by setting up the router, will give you the ability to adjust the number of threads strictly responsible for handling the database calls.  Easy scaling.  Also, by using Actors you can structure the messages between actors (e.g. a message having the results of the database call) a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Akka.future(f)` and provide your own Akka configuration file to get more threads to process your database accesses. Look at [this config file](https://gist.github.com/2973705) for example.

But you pointed it out: the real problem is in using a database driver that blocks. I don't know which DB you are using, but it's worth to take a look to MongoDB with [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org) for example. With ReactiveMongo all MongoDB operations are perfectly non-blocking and asynchronous. There is a good introduction [here](http://stephane.godbillon.com/2012/08/30/reactivemongo-for-scala-unleashing-mongodb-streaming-capabilities-for-realtime-web). Moreover, it deals very well with Play Framework (check the [ReactiveMongo Play Plugin](https://github.com/zenexity/Play-ReactiveMongo)).

EDIT: You can also check "[Configuring Playframework's internal Akka system](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/AkkaCore)" to tune the worker threads number.

Comment: I'm stuck with MySQL..., but it seems to have an async API too! Is there documentation for that config file?

Comment: Since this configuration file is actually for Akka, you can read the [Akka configuration doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/general/configuration.html).

Comment: I forgot to mention this [doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/AkkaCore) too ([configuring Playframework's internal Akka system](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/AkkaCore)).